# Hazard rate from Weibull vs. cumulative hazard plot does not match

Tags: survival, inference, weibull-distribution, actuarial-science, hazard

)

My problem is that I have HR for a factor named "Selvrisiko" and I get the

output estimates (HR) (Upper bound) (Lower bound) as:

[image]

but when I plot (Kaplan - Meier) cumulative hazard for the groups I get:

[image]

Interpretation:

group 5262 and 7015 has higer risk than 3509 while 8769 has not

but when I look at the graph it seems that the group 8769 is acutally in higher risk than 3509

What is wong? Is my Interpretation correct?